# Logging out Drupal user needs browser reload

Tags: drupal-7

When I log out of the Drupal 7 site I'm working on, I need to reload the browser before it shows I'm logged out. I tried using rules to do a redirect after log out to a Thank You page, then on that page I added a JavaScript to refresh a couple of times, then redirect to the home page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = loadRefresh;

function loadRefresh() {
  location.reload();
}

setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "/";
}, 2000);
</script>
```

That gets to the home page but it shows I'm logged in. I even tried:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
unset($GLOBALS['user']);
?>
```

but I still have to hit reload on the browser to make it work. Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: How do you log out? Normally, when you log out from a Drupal 7 site you are redirected to the site's home page and any logged-in privilege is unaivailable at that point.

Comment: I log out using one of the "logout" links user/logout. It's a caching problem obviously, but I can't figure out where I've set something wrong. The best guess I have might be in APC settings. I haven't found where APC can cause this kind of problem.

Comment: I just tried it with Chrome and Firefox, and it seems to be only happening in Firefox.

Comment: [this link](http://drupal.org/node/770774) may be relevant for your case.

Comment: @pamatt I took a look at the link, and it does seems to be similar. The solution is done by fixing Boost, which I don't use. I did a search to see if others complain about FF doing that. and there are a few. I tried one suggestion on setting FF browser.sessionstore.privacy_level higher, but that did nothing.

Comment: The issue with FF was present in earlier version of D7. Is your site up to date? And did you try to disable APC?

Comment: I haven't tried disabling APC, and yes the sites are up to date.